# Select font color before and after selection

Tags: html, css

I have a form select where the first option is a disabled default title which acts like a placeholder.

```
<select>
  <option disabled selected>Client</option>
  <option value="John">John</option>
  <option value="Pete">Pete</option>
</select>
```

I want to be able to style the font `color:#999` before user clicks on the select, then after they've made a selection, the font should change to `color:#333`. Is this possible?

Consider the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ayxeb759/

The fiddle shows that this is possible for other form elements but possibly not select. Text inputs use `::placeholder` styling then styling for the block like so:

```
/* text input before */
*:-moz-placeholder { color: #AAA; }
*::-moz-placeholder { color: #AAA; }
*:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #AAA; }
*::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #AAA; }

/* text input after */
input[type="text"] { color: #333; }
```

Checkboxes use `:checked` to alter styling after the user has made a selection.

So how can I achieve the same for select?

Comment: Your code sets, on supporting browsers, the color of the first option to `#333` permanently, since the option has the `selected` attribute whether it has been selected or not. But you write “until a real selection is made”. What should happen to it then?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I know, that's my dilemma. How do I achieve the correct styling but still have an initial placeholder/title in the select box.

Comment: Please define “correct styling”.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Before user interaction the select box should be #999. After a selection is made the select box should change to #333. Similar to an input placeholder which can be styled separately to the text input by a user.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I've edited my question and added examples and a JSFiddle to better illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be impossible with CSS alone. Although the `:checked` pseudo-class applies to `option` elements (and is supported by modern browsers), matching dynamically the selected option, the text color of the `select` element is distinct from the colors of the options. It can be set separately, but there is currently no way in CSS to set it depending on which option is selected. This means that even if you set the default dummy selection color to gray, that option text will appear in black (or whatever color is set for the `select`= in the initial state of the control.

With a little bit of JavaScript, you can fix this. You would initially set, using just CSS, the `select` element color to `#333`, and the dummy default option color to `#999`. The JavaScript code would just set the color of the `select` element according to the selection made. (It would suffice to set it to `#333`, since it should not be possible to change the selection to the initial dummy option.)

```html
<style>
select { color: #999 }
option { color: #333 }
option[selected]  { color: #999; background: white }
</style>
<select onchange=
   "if(this.value==='') {this.style.color='#999'} else {this.style.color='#333'}">
  <option disabled selected value="">Client</option>
  <option value="John">John</option>
  <option value="Pete">Pete</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, although I didn't want to use JS for this, your solution is quite non-intrusive - so if it really can't be done in CSS, this is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, a CSS-only option isn't possible.

This is what I'd do (or sort of):

Add an extra class to the selectbox which will be removed when an option is selected.

**CSS**

```
select, select:focus {
    color:#333;
}

select.placeholder {
    color:#999;
}
```

**JS**

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("select"), function(el) {
    el.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
        this.className = "";
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayxeb759/2/)

Comment: Thanks although it was a CSS solution I was looking for. It's a shame if this isn't possible when you can do the same on all other form elements. Seems silly that the select box has to stand out and look different from everything else on the page.

Comment: It is indeed. The lack of a placeholder for the select box is  definitely a gap in the spec (even HTML5), and there won't be any CSS-only solutions any time soon.